# update column through time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
    id  Prod_id Year    Quartar Start_flag  End_flag    status
1   A001    2015    1   0   0   0
2   A001    2015    2   1   0   0
3   A001    2015    3   0   0   0
4   A001    2015    4   0   0   0
5   A001    2016    1   0   0   0
6   A001    2016    2   0   0   0
7   A001    2016    3   0   1   0
8   A001    2016    4   0   0   0
9   B002    2015    1   0   0   0
10  B002    2015    2   0   0   0
11  B002    2015    3   0   0   0
12  B002    2015    4   1   0   0
13  B002    2016    1   0   1   0
14  B002    2016    2   0   0   0
15  B002    2016    3   0   0   0
16  B002    2016    4   0   0   0
17  c003    2015    1   0   1   0
18  c003    2015    2   0   0   0
19  c003    2015    3   0   1   0
20  c003    2015    4   1   0   0
21  c003    2016    1   0   0   0
22  c003    2016    2   0   0   0
23  c003    2016    3   0   0   0
24  c003    2016    4   0   0   0
```

The table has UNIQUE index using (Prod_id,Year,Quarter) & index clustered on (Prod_id,Year,Quarter).
on another word, the table is ordered by 
My table has the following:

- More than 20 million unique rows based on (Prod_id,Year,Quarter)
- Each product might have start_flag and might not.
- In case product has start flag, it might has end flag before and after start 
  flag and it might have end flag only before start flag.
- Each product start from 2010 to 2018 with 4 quarter each year.

I want to update the status column = 1 through time from start_flag to one quarter before first end_flag after start_flag. In case there is no end flag, the update will be until last records for select product.

After implementing the update, the updated table should be like this:

```
 id Prod_id Year    Quartar Start_flag  End_flag    status
1   A001    2015    1   0   0   0
2   A001    2015    2   1   0   1
3   A001    2015    3   0   0   1
4   A001    2015    4   0   0   1
5   A001    2016    1   0   0   1
6   A001    2016    2   0   0   1
7   A001    2016    3   0   1   0
8   A001    2016    4   0   0   0
9   B002    2015    1   0   0   0
10  B002    2015    2   0   0   0
11  B002    2015    3   0   0   0
12  B002    2015    4   1   0   1
13  B002    2016    1   0   1   0
14  B002    2016    2   0   0   0
15  B002    2016    3   0   0   0
16  B002    2016    4   0   0   0
17  c003    2015    1   0   1   0
18  c003    2015    2   0   0   0
19  c003    2015    3   0   1   0
20  c003    2015    4   1   0   1
21  c003    2016    1   0   0   1
22  c003    2016    2   0   0   1
23  c003    2016    3   0   0   1
24  c003    2016    4   0   0   1
```

I Already implanted a solution using pl/pgsql using cursor.But the solution using cursor it take more than 30 hours to update this column in my case.
Is there an alternate way to do this update without using cursor?
I am using PostgreSQL 10.6.
Please advice & Thank you.

Comment: . . It looks like you are updating a whole bunch of rows.  That is going to be quite slow.  You might consider recreating the table.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I didn't really understand your use case with the quarters and how the `start_flag` ranges should work over the time. So the following solution is without looking at the time part. If you could explain your time example a little bit, I am sure the following solution only need a little tweak (e.g. a `PARTITION` clause) for getting work for you.

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=236b26b0ad1bcb1ccb1b225b02625c38)

My sample data:

```
id   start_flag   end_flag
1    0            0
2    1            0
3    0            0
4    0            0
5    0            1
6    0            0
7    1            0
8    0            1
9    0            0
10   0            1
11   0            0
12   0            1
13   1            0
14   0            0
16   0            0
```

The query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    GREATEST(
         first_value(start_flag - end_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY sum ORDER BY id), 
         0
    ) as status
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(start_flag + end_flag) OVER (ORDER BY id)
    FROM mytable
) s
```

The result:

```
id   start_flag   end_flag   status
1    0            0          0
2    1            0          1
3    0            0          1
4    0            0          1
5    0            1          0
6    0            0          0
7    1            0          1
8    0            1          0
9    0            0          0
10   0            1          0
11   0            0          0
12   0            1          0
13   1            0          1
14   0            0          1
16   0            0          1
```

Explanation:

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

1. Cumulative `SUM` of every potential "status change" (`start_flag` or `end_flag`). This creates groups. In every group the same status exist. (see `SUM` column in fiddle)
2. `first_value` window function: for every group check if the status change was done by `start_flag` (positive) or `end_flag` (negative)
3. `GREATEST()` normalizes the negative values to zero.

---

Edit: Adding the `prod_id` and `year/quarters`

All in all the whole use case is quiet similar - just using window functions:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=95d7c57b11ec81c503f6be620b3ca1d7)

1. Instead of ordering by `id`, I am ordering by `year, quarter`
2. Instead of looking to the whole data set I am using a partition (over the `prod_id`)for the window functions:

Expanded query:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    GREATEST(
         first_value(start_flag - end_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_id, sum ORDER BY year, quarter), 
         0
    ) as status
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(start_flag + end_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_id ORDER BY year, quarter)
    FROM mytable
) s
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
each product has status each quarter from 2010 to 2018 so each product will have 32 records and will have status either 0 or 1 so time is main factor in my update. I am ordering the table by prod_id,year,quarter.
I want to update the status for one product from start_flag.

Comment: Expanded the query to your use case

Comment: @Eyla did this help? Please don't forget to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    start_date = subquery.to_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            year,
            quarter,
            to_date(concat(year, quarter), 'YYYYQ')
        from
            table1
    ) AS subquery
WHERE
    table1.year = subquery.year
    and table1.quarter = subquery.quarter
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    end_date = subquery.end_of_month
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            year,
            quarter,
            (
                date_trunc('month', start_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
            ) :: date AS end_of_month
        from
            table1
    ) AS subquery
WHERE
    table1.year = subquery.year
    and table1.quarter = subquery.quarter
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).